# обойти сайты не нагружая сервера

Tags: php, веб-программирование, парсер

Есть много доменов, которые нужно обойти, если начать в несколько потоков долбить сайты можно попасть на поддомены, принадлежащие одному сайту и словить бан или несколько сайтов хостятся у одного хостера и забанить может хостер.

Вопрос: как можно равномерно распределить запросы, чтобы ни сайт, ни хостер не банил?

Вариант использования прокси не подходит, т.к.:

1. ожидаемые данные неизвестны
2. время обхода увеличивается в 10 раз.

Мне на ум приходит только 1 вариант - распределять по ip, т.е. берём пачку 100000 доменов (уник) и проверяем, чтобы у них были разные ip. Но это не очень вариант, т.к. у 1 хостера более 1 ip на сервер скорее всего.

Может у вас есть какие мысли на этот счёт?

Comment: А нужно HTTP GET или HEAD выполнять?

Comment: HTTP GET т.е. я полностью беру страницу

Comment: если сервер не может обслужить больше какого то кол-ва запросов, то единственный способ это обойти - помочь хостеру - например, добавив серверов или договорившись с админами сайта. Или растягивать время.

Comment: @KoVadim у меня 30млн. доменов на обход, как вы себе это представляете "помочь хостеру"? Меня просто банят по фильтрам из-за повышенной нагрузки, также левые данные отдают типа 500 код ответа, хотя сайт однозначно работает

Comment: @Василий ну тогда только приобретать себе много ip-адресов, желательно в не слишком похожих подсетях

Comment: @Василий и как всегда возникает вопрос - зачем 30млн доменов насиловать? Возможно, решение куда проще, если Вы расскажете свою задачу.

Comment: @KoVadim есть компания X, которая производит товар, ей нужно найти все компании Y, которые продают аналогичный товар, чтобы предложить им свою продукцию. В общем обойти сайты - это константа